# PhoneGap is not opening

Tags: windows-7

I have recently downloaded PhoneGap Desktop on my Windows 7, but unfortunately when I try to open it **first time** ( after installing ) it stuck on Loading screen it shows only loading circle and nothing happens. Any idea what to do?

Comment: 1/ PhoneGap Desktop is **beta** software. 2/ "The PhoneGap Desktop app officially only supports Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. You can try to use the current builds and see if it works for you. Some other users have found that it still works."

Comment: Can you please give me the link of current build

Comment: It's on the [Get Started](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/) page.